# Display table dynamically from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

all masters.
 I have an below array

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 13
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 21
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 13
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 21
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 13
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 21
                )

        )

)
```

In above Array The first Node [1] is my color value. Inside it [2] is my size attribute and this value. in same child node their is [3] is my type attribute and its value. I want to display this in HTML Table format like this.
1 2 3 should be goes into  according this below table will be display.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  
 </table>
```

if their is no 3 node table will be display like this

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
     </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>12</td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>12</td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      
     </table>
```

Please Help me to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try to use `foreach` to loop through your array?

Comment: Yes, Hello, I want create <td></td> dynamically based on inner node ( [1] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 12 [2] => 13 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 21 ) ) whether it is [2] [3] or only [2] or more than 2 node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `range`, `array_map`, `end` and `current` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$parent_keys = range(1, count(current($arr)) + 1);
echo "<table><tr>" . 
        implode("", array_map(function($v){
            return "<th>".$v."</th>"; }, $parent_keys)
        );
echo "</tr>";

foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
    if (count($item) > 1 && is_array(end($item))) $last = current(end($item));
    reset($item);
    foreach (current($item) as $v) {
        echo "<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v</td>". (isset($last)? "<td>$last</td>" : "") ."</tr>";
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

[**DEMO** link](https://eval.in/634602)

Each sequence of cells within `tr` is comprised of "key"(array key of parent level) **+** value from the current array item(which you called *Node[2]*) **+** value from *Node[3]*(**if exists**).
Number of `<th>` cells depends on how many elements have each nested item(node[2], node[3]) ... including key from *parent* level

Comment: Thank You very much. Can you please explain this.

Comment: @PravinBankar, added some explanation

Comment: if you want i will give you hole scenario which comes dynamically. Their will be each node differ from every time  based on user selection.

Comment: Hello, I want create <td></td> dynamically  based on inner node 
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 13
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 21
                )

        )  whether it is [2] [3] or  only [2] or more than  2 node